# PDO prepared statements Like and OR statements used together

Tags: php, pdo

I'm trying to say if all the 'OR's match then display. If it's remotely close to the custodian then display (LIKE)
To Leo, Yes I tried :custodian heres whole code. I commented out what you suggested because that's what works for now. (also changed the sql). I'm curious if the first query where I'm trying to get the 'count' matters. Let me know. Thanks.

```
$q = $_GET['q'];
$STH = $dbh->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM inv_assets WHERE po = :query OR serialNum = :query OR dop = :query OR purchaseFrom = :query OR custodian = :query");
    $STH->bindParam(':query', $q);
            //$STH->bindParam(':custodian', '%'.$q.'%');
    $STH->execute();

    if ($STH->fetchColumn() > 0) {
        $STH = NULL;
        $STH = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM inv_assets WHERE po = :query OR serialNum = :query OR dop =:query OR purchaseFrom = :query OR custodian = :query");
        $STH->bindParam(':query', $q);
        //$STH->bindParam(':custodian', '%'.$q.'%');
                    $STH->execute();
        showTable($STH,$perms);
```

Comment: please add more info as it seems your question is not clear

Answer (score 2):

`LIKE` replaces `=` not `OR`

Example:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name 
FROM student_details 
WHERE first_name LIKE 'S%' OR last_name LIKE 'A%';
```

Take a look here: [SQL Comparison Keywords](http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-like-in-operators.htm)

Comment: So OR and LIKE can't be used together? The link didn't mention OR, but that's kind of what I gathered.

Comment: `OR` has nothing to do with `LIKE` and they can be used altogether as @soufiane-hassou said :)

Comment: My question boils down to how do you use bindParam() with LIKE considering the need for % ?

Comment: @zemerick: You include the %s in the value you're binding - `... custodian LIKE :query ...` and `$st->execute(array(':query' => 'foo%'));` or whatever.

Answer (score 2):

An example of how to do PDO LIKE Queries.

```
$STH = $dbh->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM inv_assets 
                      WHERE po = :query OR serialNum = :query OR dop = :query 
                      OR purchaseFrom = :query OR custodian LIKE :custodian");

$ret = $STH->execute(array(':custodian' => '%'.$query.'%',':query' => $query));
```

Example with bindParam:

```
<?php

$STH = $dbh->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM inv_assets 
                      WHERE po = :query OR serialNum = :query OR dop = :query 
                      OR purchaseFrom = :query OR custodian LIKE :custodian");

$STH->bindParam(':custodian', '%'.$q.'%');
$STH->bindParam(':query', $q);
$STH->execute();

?>
```

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference in /home/p16adm6h/public_html/inventory/search.php on line 147

That's after adding your extra bindParam();

Comment: Did you also change `custodian LIKE :custodian` in your SQL query above?

Comment: BTW: when using the array as argument to `execute`, the starting `:` is not required, saves typing ;)

Comment: Oh: and use `bindValue` if you want to put the result of an expression straight into `$STH => :custodian`... `bindParam` only does references to actual variables.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$STH = $dbh->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM inv_assets 
                      WHERE po = :query OR serialNum = :query OR dop = :query 
                      OR purchaseFrom = :query OR custodian LIKE :custodian");

$custodian = "%".$q."%";
$STH->bindParam(':custodian', $custodian);
$STH->bindParam(':query', $q);
$STH->execute();

?>
```

this will avoid passing parameter 2 by reference error and works